# How do i delete item from radlistview in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

i'm trying to use radlistview's delete item function in my Nativescript core app, so far what i have tried isn't working...
My data is gotten from my remote php using fetch API

```
 fetch("https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/getOtherImages.php?user=" + encodeURIComponent(email)).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {

    viewModel.set("images", res.imagess);
   }).catch((err) => {

    });
```

This is my javascript code to delete the item

```
DeleteImage: function (args) {
      var toast = Toast.makeText("Deleted");
      toast.show();
      var target = args.object;
      var tappedItemData = target.bindingContext;
      this.items.some(function (item, index) {
      if(item.id === tappedItemData.id) {
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
        return false;
      }
    });
    },
```

Comment: Is it an ObservableArray, if not you should use one. Regular array won't trigger change detection in {N} Core.

Comment: @Manoj thank you, i was able to get it to delete. but now it deletes all the items. how do i fix it

Comment: Please share a Playground sample

Comment: @Manoj the issue is with the deleteItem function in the view-model. [Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=TkJ6IS&v=5)

Comment: You are not using ObservableArray at first which you suppose to, while updating you shouldn't create new array but just splice items on existing array.

Comment: please, attach a sample code in playground

Comment: @Manoj thanks, ffixed it

Comment: @Peter fixed it already, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it, for the fetch

```
fetch("https://adekunletestprojects.000webhostapp.com/skog/getOtherImages.php?user=" + encodeURIComponent(email)).then((response) => response.json()).then((res) => {
    const imagesObs = new ObservableArray(res.imagess);
    viewModel.set("images", imagesObs);

    }).catch((err) => {
    });
```

for the deleting the item

```
images: [],
DeleteImage: function (args) {
      var target = args.object;
      var index = target.index;
      var val = index;
      var f;
      var found = this.images.some(function(item, index) { f = index; return item.id == val; });

      if (!found) {
          return false;
      }

        this.images.splice(f, 1);
    },
```